# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at {Component}.render in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am Passing my Array to props of sidebar Component like this.and i want to access it in my child component...

When i save the code and go to browser... i am getting this error message
[image: Here is a error message]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import './styles.scss';

import Sidebar from './../../components/sidebar';
import Header from './../../components/header';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

buildComponent = props => {
    console.log("Props", props.children);

    var items = [
        {
            "link": "facebook.com",
            "title": "Facebook"
        },
        {
            "link": "google.com",
            "title": "Google"
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <Sidebar name={items} />
                    <div className="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                        {props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

render() {
    return this.buildComponent(this.props);
}
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
children: PropTypes.any
};
```

And want props data here in child component..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';




export default class Sidebar extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();

}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                <ul className="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li className="fa fa-plus"><Link to="/feed">For Your Approval</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/article">Active</Link></li>
                    <li><a href="">{this.props.items.map((title) => <li>{title}</li>)}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rejected</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Send For Approval</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Draft</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Archied</a></li>

                </ul>
                <ul className="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li><a href="">Brand Safety</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

I am following tutorial, but getting this error, I am new to reactjs , please help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're not passing the 'items' prop to Sidebar. You're just passing name. You need to do `<Sidebar items={items}>`

Comment: Upvoted. Good catch. This also need conditional check before doing .map as @Bhojendra mentioned

Comment: This works for me , it was a silly mistake i passed name to <Sidebar name={item} >

When i pass items to sidebar it works <Sidebar items={items}>
By the way Good Catch!!
Thank You  @Ignacio

Answer (score 2):

The props in sidebar component, you're passing as `name`. So, do this:

```
this.props.name && this.props.name.map(...)
```

The map method will work only if name props is not undefined. And it is necessary to check if it has value. Because at initial render (renders even with null), you may get error using map. So, checking it is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Add `console.log(this.props)` to your `Sidebar`'s render method to see what you are receiving.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of `super(props)` just to make `this.props` available in the constructor

Comment: You are right.  My answer is incorrect, though having the console.log in the Sidebar render would have helped to expose the mismatch between items and name props.